# How to connect to a remote neo4j instance using a GraphDatabaseService?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, neo4j, distributed-transactions, jca

We currently have a JavaEE deployment using Glassfish and the JCA [neo4j-connector](https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector), which means neo4j is started as an `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` for which we can only use neo4j community.

My boss requires me to investigate on how to add high-availability, replication, and globally all services neo4j enterprise could allow us to use. In that direction, I'm currently thinking about modifying that CJA connector to no more use an embedded neo4j instance, but rather connect to a separate process eventually running on the same machine.

There are, however, some questions on that topic.

First of all, it seems there was in earlier versions of neo4j a `RemoteGraphDatabaseService`. it seems to be gone. is it really ? More important, our application uses JCA to coordinate transactions using XA between the various components. How can I keep that transaction coordination to an external neo4j instance considering the REST API doesn't seems to support customizable transaction size (one REST call IS one transaction for neo4j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be pretty easy to modify the JCA connector to use `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase` instead. You just have to pass in the config that is needed for HA, backup etc.

Comment: Was thinking so but, in such a case, the neo4j instance will be embedded in Glassfish, no , or do yout hink about a replication strategy where there is one slave neo4j in glassfish and one master outside ?

Comment: The master and slave will be whereever they are elected or you configure them to be. You should make sure to write to the master though.

Comment: @Michael_Hunger why forcing write to master ? neo4j docs state that writing to slaves is possible, since there is an internal replication mechanism. am i wrong ?